# How is the root folder of Multi build project determined in gradle?

Tags: gradle

Before projects are built Settings object is created which contains rootDir variable.

> rootDir : The root directory of the build. The root directory is the project directory of the root project.

Also the documentation states it can never be null.

```
File getRootDir()

Returns the root directory of the build. The root directory is the project directory of the root project.

Returns:
    The root directory. Never returns null.
```

I want to know how is rootDir determined in Multi build project. Is it the highest level directory containing build.gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details can be discovered in [test specification](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/test/groovy/org/gradle/initialization/layout/BuildLayoutFactoryTest.groovy)

Simple version: it goes up directory hierarchy and searches for `settings.gradle` file. If it is not found or when started with `--no-search-upward` it can return current directory. Or you can pass location of `settings.gradle` using `--settings-file`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. What if `settings.gradle` file is in current directory as well as it's parent directory?

Comment: then it is the current directory according to "returns closest ancestor directory that contains a settings file" in the linked test.